# My website doesn't work in I.E. (but does in chrome and firefox)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, web

I have created a website [biolonline.co.uk](http://www.biolonline.co.uk) and I think it looks quite good in Firefox and Chrome (even though I am not an expert).

However, I have no idea how to get it to work in Internet Explorer.  Nothing centers properly, and the floating static elements such as the red button on the right and the navbar on the top do not float/stay in same position.

If anyone would be able to take a look and tell me where I've gone wrong I would greatly appreciate it.  I've been thinking about this for ages.

Comment: Welcome to the club. Almost all problems I have ever had with sites have shown up in IE only.

Comment: Argh...beat me too it...first words I thought of when I saw the title.

Comment: Start with [valid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will never get IE to attempt to perform like the other far more modern browsers without a proper doctype. You are in quirks mode without one. Add this to your first line: `<!DOCTYPE html>` . Then let's see where things are.

Comment: The strange thing is when i add <!DOCTYPE html> to the index.php and any other page it looks terrible in both browsers.  Then I added <!DOCTYPE html> to first line of include.php (the PHP include on every page) and removed it from the index.php - It worked briefly on internet explorer, until I went on the website again using IE to find it the same as before!  For a second I thought it was working great and then it stops working.  Any ideas?

Comment: @user1527487 - You are probably forgetting to refresh the page after making changes. The older version is still in your browser's cache. Also, adding the doctype will make browsers perform according to standards so some things may move around on you since you were originally in quirks.

Comment: no clearing the cache didn't work - the stange thing is that if I press F5 it stays the same.  But retype www.biolonline.co.uk into the address bar it reloads an reverts back to normal (the same as closing IE and going back on it again) - I'm wondering if its to do with not having DOCTYPE HTML on the actual index.php and only having it in the PHP include (but it looks terrible with the DOCTYPE on the index.php!!  Thanks for your help.  For a moment I thought it was solved and then the nightmare of IE appeared once again!

Comment: @user1527487 - I see the issue. You put the doctype in but it's not in the right place. It must be the very first line at the top of the page and nowhere else!

Comment: This is what happen's when I put doctype on the index.php page : http://www.biolonline.co.uk/doctype.php

I want it to look like this http://www.biolonline.co.uk (only on chrome)

ON IE THE navbar and discuss button stay in the same position now which is good - but the main div is positioned at the top of the page not in the center as shown on the homepage.  So maybe all I need to figure out now is how to sort out the div

Answer (score 1):

A good way to get around this is to have a separate style sheet for IE, and then make it work good separately in IE. Use a HTML if to restrict it to IE. This is a common way of doing it, and there are quite a few sites that do this. One example is http://www.wordpress.com/.

- Check out point 4 in [this article](http://scarfoo.com/archives/16), it has some ideas.
- [This article](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/fixedPosition.html) explains a way to make it fixed, as well as explaining some other related things.

Here is some example code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylepath" />
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link href="stylepath" rel="stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->
```